# Segmentation Fault 11 Confusion

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The assignment I have is reading in a test.m file, parsing it, and putting the pertinent information into an array of type statement (of which I create). I've completed the assignment for the most part. The only thing that is wrong is that I am getting a Segmentation Fault 11 at the very end of the output. Thinking it may be something wrong with the output section I'm doing, so I commented it out to see. It still gave me a seg fault. It always gives me a seg fault at the very end of the program, no matter what I comment out. I am so baffled as to what's causing it. What should I do about this? Since everything else is working, should I just ignore it?

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LC_SIZE 16
#define FREAD_SIZE 1024
#define STATES_SIZE 1024

FILE *ifp;
int linetotal;
int locals[LC_SIZE];
int localspot = 0; // localspot = # of locals
int EP;

typedef char STRING[256];

typedef struct {
  STRING label;
  STRING opcode;
  STRING arg;
} statement;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  //statement states[STATES_SIZE] = {"(NULL)"};

  char str[256];
  const char newline[3] = "\n";
  const char space[2] = " ";
  char *token;
  unsigned long length;

  ifp = (argc > 1) ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : NULL;

  if (ifp == NULL) {
    printf("Input file not available\n");
    return -1; }

  fread(str, FREAD_SIZE, 1, ifp);

  token = strtok(str, space);

  statement states[STATES_SIZE];
   for (int i = 0; i < STATES_SIZE; i++) {
    strcpy(states[i].label, "(null)");
    strcpy(states[i].opcode, "(null)");
    strcpy(states[i].arg, "(null)"); }

  while (token != NULL) {

    length = strlen(token);
    if (length > 1 ) { strcpy(str, &token[length-1]); }

    // comment check
    if ((strncmp(token, "/", 1) == 0) || (strcmp(str, "/") == 0)) {
      token = strtok(NULL, newline);
      //printf("Comment :: %s\n", token);
      token = strtok(NULL, space);
    }

    // local check
    else if (strcmp(token, "LC:") == 0) { 
      token = strtok(NULL, space);
      //printf("==LC here==\n");
      locals[localspot] = atoi(token);
      localspot++;
      //printf("Local variable %i = %s\n", localspot, token);
      token = strtok(NULL, space);
    }

    // starting point check
    else if (strcmp(token, "EP:") == 0) {
      token = strtok(NULL, space);
      EP = atoi(token);
      //printf("\nEP: %i\n", EP);
    }

    // label check
    else if (strcmp(str, ":") == 0) {
      //printf("--Label found :: %s\n", token);
      strcpy(states[linetotal].label, token);
      token = strtok(NULL, space);
    }

    // a function
    else if ((strcmp(token, "") != 0) && (strcmp(token, "\n") != 0)){
      //printf("Function :: %s\n", token);
      strcpy(states[linetotal].opcode, token);
      if ((strcmp(token, "halt") != 0) && (strcmp(token, "mul") != 0) && (strcmp(token,     "sub") != 0)) {
        token = strtok(NULL, space); 
        strcpy(states[linetotal].arg, token);
        //printf("arg :: %s\n", token);
      }
      token = strtok(NULL, space);
      linetotal++;
    }
    else
      break;
  } 

  // the output process
  printf("System State:\n-------------\n");
  printf("prog.PC: %i\n", EP);
  printf("Number of locals: %i\n", localspot);
  for (int i = 0; i < localspot; i++) 
    printf("Local %i: %i\n", i, locals[i]);
  printf("prog.PROGSIZE: %i\n\n", linetotal);

  printf("       Program      \n--------------------\n\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < linetotal; i++) 
    printf("%.6s %.5s %.6s\n", states[i].label, states[i].opcode, states[i].arg);

  fclose(ifp);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: dont ignore it - run `gdb` and do a backtrace (find out what line is causing the segfault)

Comment: `fread(str, FREAD_SIZE, 1, ifp);` where `str` is an automatic variable `char str[256]` in `main()`, and `FREAD_SIZE` is `#define FREAD_SIZE 1024`, is recipe for disaster, and it only gets worse from there. And `statement states[STATES_SIZE];`, where each `statement` is a struct of three `char[256]` arrays equates to adding 768KB *minimum* to your local stack space of `main()`. If it isn't brushing up against your default limit it is certainly close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `fread`, you read raw data from a file. That means that the string you read is not null-terminated. All the `strxxx` functions operate on null-terminated strings. Because `str` is not null-terminated, they treat the garbage after the real data as part of the string -- of undetermined length.

You should also pay attention to what WhozCraig said and make your `str` big enough, which also means to reserve one extra char for the terminating null character. It was a good idea to define a constant for the buffer size, but you should use it throughout your program consistently.

Anyway: null-terminate your string. `fread` returns the items successfully read, so:

```
char str[FREAD_SIZE + 1];
int n;

/* ... */

n = fread(str, 1. FREAD_SIZE, ifp);
if (n < 0) exit(1);
str[n] = '\0';
```

Note that I have swapped the second and third arguments to `fread`. The second is the size of each item, here a `char`. The third is the maximum number of items to read. The return value will depend on that, because it returns the number of items read, not the number of bytes read.

**Edit**: The char buffer `str` must, of course, be big enough to hold ther terminating `'\0'`. Otherwise setting `str[n]` will write beyond the buffer if the maximum number of chars are read. (Thanks for WhozCraig for spotting that. Should really have though of that myself.)

Comment: +1 I would actually read `FREAD_SIZE-1` in the `fread()` call. If the buffer hits full capacity `str[n] = 0` will write one-char past end-of-array and invoke UB. The idea is certainly correct regardless. Or declare `str` as `FREAD_SIZE+1` length. Either way works.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Quite stupid to have missed this. I'll edit.